# How can I reduce latency on VLC

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, video-streaming, latency, decoding

I 'm working on a video streaming application. Server is a Linux machine *(ffmpeg-ffserver)* and client is a Windows machine *(vlc player)*.

There is a latency of about 6 seconds. Despite the fact that server and client start together, client starts displaying stream, after about 6 seconds. I noticed that client **displays from the first frame stored to it's buffer**, resulting to a constant delay of about 6 seconds.

How can I fix this? Is there any option (command line maybe) to decrease buffer size? I zeroed parameters shown below on client side, but latency still exists.

[image]